# How can we code a custom map where each block (house) is clickable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How can we code the below image in flutter where each orange block in image should be clickable and on clicking it should open a dialog.

[image: Code the image]

Comment: everything shown on top of `google_maps_flutter`?

Comment: this image is view of future buildings which will be constructed in the area..currently google maps can show only plain ground..if i use google_maps_flutter.. how can i create the street paths?

Comment: you can use [GoogleMapController](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController-class.html) to get current visible region and draw your custom paths using `CustomPaint` which could be a parent of your `GoogleMap` widget

Comment: Okay thanks for your response ..I'll give it a try

Comment: You can also add polygons to Google Maps widget with `polygons` property when creating with `GoogleMap` constructor. These polygons can accept tap events.